# wrong output because of backgrounded processes

Tags: bash, multiprocessing

If I run the script with `./test.sh 100` I do not get the output 100 because I am using a thread. What do I have to do to get the expected output? (I must not change `test.sh` though.)

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="number.txt"
echo "0" > $FILE
for (( x=1; x<=$1; x++)); do
    exec "./increment.sh" $FILE &
done
wait
cat $FILE
```

increment.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
value=(< "$1")
let value++
echo $value > "$1"
```

EDIT

Well I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
flock $1 --shared 2>/dev/null
value=(< "$1")
let value++
echo $value > "$1"
```

Now i get something like 98 99 all the time if I use `./test.sh 100`
I is not working very well and I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: You might be confusing threads and processes. Bash only starts external processes, not threads. Both can be used for parallelism, but with different implications.

Comment: what do you have to change to ensure sequential operation of a set of asynchrounous threads?.... Heaven and Earth.

Comment: ..start "troubleshooting" with man 7 builtins page. ==>


      exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
              If command is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new process is created.  The arguments become the arguments to command.  If the -l option is supplied, the shell places a  dash
              at the beginning of the zeroth argument passed to command.  This is what login(1) does.  The -c option causes command to be executed with an empty environment. [...] <===

Comment: @zneak, all, I updated question title and tags to remove the reference to "multithreading."  There's a real question here underneath that misleading reference.

Comment: Without some coordination on the access to `number.txt`, your results could be anything. You're spawning a bunch of background processes, all of which read the file and then re-write it. Probably a bunch of them will "break", because the redirection to write the file first truncates it, which means if one of the other processes tries to read it before the `echo` finishes and writes a valid value, it will read nothing, which is difficult to increment, and so on... Looks like the beginnings of a chaos generator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `test.sh` really cannot be improved, then each instance of `increment.sh` must serialize it's own access to $FILE.

Filesystem locking is the obvious solution for this under UNIX.  However, there is no shell builtin to accomplish this.  Instead, you must rely on an external utility program like [flock](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock), [setlock](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/setlock.html), or [chpst -l|-L](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html).  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
  flock 100          # Lock *exclusively* (not shared)
  value=(< "$1")
  let value++
  echo $value > "$1"
) 100>>"$1"          # A note of caution
```

A note of caution:  using the file you'll be modifying as a lockfile gets tricky quickly — it's easy to truncate in shell when you didn't mean to, and the mixing of access modes above might offend some people — but the above avoids gross mistakes.